# ReferenceError when accessing Error object in Catch block In VS Code Debugger

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm having this odd issue where I cannot access the Error object in the catch block. Interestingly enough, If I print it out it works fine.

[image]

Not possible to access it in the debugger

[image: Not possible to access it in the debugger]

There error that causes is:
`21611 MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: myFirstDatabase.pddeals index: pId_1 dup key: { pId: 21611 } app.ts:36 duplicates`

Comment: My start script  "start": "ts-node-dev ./app.ts"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by assigning the error to a variable.

```
   try {
        let newvalue = await new models.pdDealModel({...order});
        await newvalue.save();
    } catch (err:unknown) {
        if (err instanceof Error) {
            const message = err.message
            const isDuplicated = message.match('pId_1')?.[0] ? true : null
            if (isDuplicated) {
                duplicates.push(order)
            }
    }
```